# Keras Embedding Layer not accepting input

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, embedding

I am trying to create a forecasting model which takes the lag features along with embeddings to predict next 10 days cumulative value. Embedding layer is trained by using the order basket with gensim.

Below is my network:

```
from keras.layers import Embedding, Flatten, Input, Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Activation

inp = Input(shape=(1, )) #ucode length will be 1  
x = Embedding(len(model.wv.vocab), WV_DIM,
              weights=[model.wv.vectors],
              trainable=False)(inp)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(32, activation='relu', name='Embedding_out')(x)

features_input = Input(shape=(122,)) ##lag Features
concat = concatenate([features_input, x],name="ConcatenatedwFeatures")
output = Dense(256, activation="relu",name="L1_Relu")(concat) 
output = Dense(128, activation="relu",name="L2_Relu")(output)
output = Dense(1)(output) 

EmbeddingModel = Model(inputs=[inp,features_input], outputs=output)
EmbeddingModel.summary()
```

```
adam = optimizers.adam(clipvalue=1.,lr=3e-4) 
EmbeddingModel.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer=adam,                  
              metrics = ['mae', 'mse'])

hist = EmbeddingModel.fit([ucode_array[20:25],X_train[20:25]], [y_train[20:25]], validation_split=0.05,
                 epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

```
Error:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'I33946'


Input Values:
ucode_array=sales_train_grid['ucode']
```

```
ucode_array[20:25]

15683    I33946
15685    I33946
15687    I33946
15688    126310
15689    126310
Name: ucode, dtype: object
```

Testing if value is present in embedding layer:

```
test1=model.wv.most_similar(positive=['I00731'], topn=10)
display(test1)
[x[0] for x in test1]
```

Returns 10 similar objects. Returns none if i had pasted any random values.

Following things tried:
1. ucode_array[20:25].values
2. ucode_array[20:25].values.tolist()

---

gensim version:     3.4.0
TensorFlow version:     1.12.0

Comment: It simply means your training data contains `string` values which for sure cannot be converted to `float`. Vectorize your input and I believe it will be fine.

Comment: I am trying to vectorize using the embeddings.

Comment: That's fine. Just make sure your `training set` does not have any `string` or `object` value. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: solved it .. forgot about the basics :(
 ```tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(list(model.wv.vocab.keys()))
encoded_ucode = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(ucode_array)```
used this encoded_ucode as input1.

Comment: I have submitted the answer you can accept it. This will help others to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, we have to feed numerical values to the `training` process. 
Making sure converting all the `object` and `strings` to embeddings will solve the problem.

putting down basic preprocessing operation which before we actually, for others to find this helpful.

sample code.

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(list(model.wv.vocab.keys())
encoded_ucode = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(ucode_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this,
use `float` to convert a string into a float. I guess this will solve your problem.